# Jsp based spring mvc to rest mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have started learning spring mvc sometime back, for practice i was developing a small application it used jsp as its frontend and spring mvc as its backend.

Now i am trying to move from jsp based application to REST based application. I am using AngularJs and html for my front end. Now my goal is that the front end and backend should communicate via REST only. My front end applications is a multipage application, to navigate from one page to another i have created hyperlinks(href).

but the hyperlinks are not working, as i always get a 404 response so i ended up writing a logic less request mapping method.

This is the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("query/")
public class QueryController {
    @Autowired
    private SpaceAccessorService spaceAccessorService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "queryboard", method = GET)
    public String queryBoard() {
        return "query/queryboard";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "TabbedSpaces", method = GET)
    public String spaces() {
        return "query/TabbedSpaces";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "getListOfAllSpacesForGrid")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    List<String> getListOfAllSpacesForGrid(@RequestParam String gridName) {
        return spaceAccessorService.getAllSpacesForGrid(gridName);
    }
}
```

this is my servlet xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:/config.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>
```

I was under the impression that if i removew ViewResolver my href should work just like normal html but it always returns 404 status. I want to get rid of these request mapping, it should work with just

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is viewResolver do not serve static html pages all you need to do is to add your html pages as resources like :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

and include it into a jsp using angular or jsp:include

Comment: that is already in place. but my html pages are not under resources they are under WEB-INF/html/query/ . I will check if keeping under resources works or not, but is that the correct way to organize ?

Comment: No it didnt work, i tried with .jsp but its not a working but on a second note, should uri correspond to view name or it should be the responsibility of controller to return the view name as it will allow me to change view later for same url ?

Comment: no, the controller who should return the view name without extention but it must be a jsp page under the "prefix" property in viewResolver and inside this jsp refere to your html page from webapp/resources with angular (ng-view) or with jsp:include